# Show that $|5|=2^{n-2}$ when $n \ge 3$ in $U(2^n)$

Tags: group-theory, algebras

Show that $|5|=2^{n-2}$ when $n \ge 3$ in $U(2^n)$.

I wrote $$5^{2^{n-2}}=\left(1+2^2\right)^{2^{n-2}}=1+2^{2}.2^{n-2}+\frac{2^{n-2}.(2^{n-2}-1)}{2!}2^4+....+\frac{2^{n-2}.(2^{n-2}-1).(2^{n-2}-2)..(2^{n-2}-k+1)}{k!}2^{2k}+..+{2^{2}}^{2^{n-2}}$$

In mod$(2^n)$, all the terms should go to $0$ except $1$ which is the first term.

It does hold for $n=3$ and $n=4$ .... I am not able to prove it in general case

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with this is to use the identity
$$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b).$$
So that
$$5^{2^{n-2}}-1=(5^{2^{n-3}}+1)(5^{2^{n-3}}-1)=\cdots.$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: SO u are suggesting to use induction?? Assume it is for $5^{2^{n-3}}$?? i.e $2^n$ divides it. Now $2$ always divides $5^{2^{n-3}}+1$. Hence $$2^{n+1}$$ divides the whole thing??

Comment: Can I not do it the way I have done??

Comment: Yes, I find it easier this way. Also note that $5^{2^{k}}+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ to show $5^{2^{n-3}}\nequiv 1\pmod{2^n}$. Your approach works, but needs more complicated calculations.